# Value/Input lifecycle issues

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a weird scenario, and maybe I'm not doing this right.  I  have two date pickers one for a `start_date` and one for a `end_date`.  When the `start_date` changes and it's date `isAfter` the `end_date`, the `start_date` should become the `end_date`. However, the first change works fine, however, any change (that is after the end_date) does not fire and the original date is shown on any attempt afterward.

Vue:

```
<date-picker :value="start_date" @input="changeStartDate" />
<date-picker :value="end_date" @input="changeEndDate" />
```

Script:

```
...
data() {
    return {
        start_date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        end_date: moment().add(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    };
},
methods: {
    changeStartDate(value) {
        console.log('value', value);

        let start_date = moment(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        let end_date = moment(this.end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

        if (start_date.isAfter(end_date)) { start_date = end_date.clone(); }

        this.start_date = start_date;
    },
    changeEndDate(value) {
        // Similar code as above
    }
}
...
```

So if I have a range of March 10th, 2017 to March 17th, 2017 and I change the `start_date` to March 24th, 2017, the first time this fires it switches the date to March 17th, 2017 as expected.  However, AFTER the first fire if I do it again, and change to March 24th, 2017 again, it changes the `start_date` to March 24th, 2017 and does not honor the isAfter rule.

Any ideas what might be happening here?

**UPDATE**

After doing a bit of debugging, I notice what is happening.

1. The date works fine the first time because the date changes from March 10th, 2017 to March 24th, 2017.
2. If code changes the start_date to the end_date which changes the value and updates the UI.
3. The second time it fires, it changes it visually, and changes the value, but when the event fires again, it's the "same" date that was passed previously -- Vuejs sees it as unchanged, so it doesn't update it.
4. If I change the value to something before the end_date, it works again.

So maybe the question is how do I get VueJS to fire the event every time the data changes regardless if it's the same data or not?

Comment: What does end_date.clone() do?

Comment: It just makes a copy of the moment element so any manipulation you do to it doesn't effect the original moment object.  Cause the moment objects are "by ref".

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a moment object back to the start_date variable, but instead it should be a moment formatted back to a string, like this:

```
this.start_date = start_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

So when the if statement is true, the end_date cloned moment object is still transformed into a string.